# Replace function of JavaScript don't work

Tags: javascript

I have next code in javascript:

```
csvReport.name = "My New Report";
$scope.filename = csvReport.name.replace(" ", "_");
```

But I get `$scope.filename = My_New Report`. Not all spaces replacing.

What is it?

Comment: Why did you tag this `performance`?

Comment: all answers below are correct, yet none of the authors care to upvote the other correct ones... that's a bit of a disappointment :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.replace` will always replace the first occurence except if you use regular expression like that :

```
csvReport.name.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
"My New Report".replace(/ /g,'_')
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAsVu/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression with a global switch (`g`) to actually replace all instances, like this:

```
csvReport.name = "My New Report";
$scope.filename = csvReport.name.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `replace` only replace first appearance of first argument. You can use regular expression to replace in whole string.

Try this:

```
if (!String.replaceAll) {
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(replace, value) {
        var regexpStr = replace.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
        return this.replace(new RegExp(regExpStr, 'g'), value);
    };
}
```

This way you have additional function that works on whole string.

Comment: This work for the space, but it is dangerous if he want to replace character like `.` since `.` mean every character in regExp. However you can escape in your function with a regexp. Or escape it when calling the function : `.replaceAll('\\.', '_')`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I have modified my answer with adding escaping `replace` string for `regexp` special characters.